# High Score not Working in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a high score script in my game. I use the same code in my other game and it works but in this game it gives me an error :

> input string was not in the correct format

this is my code :

```
private Rigidbody2D Rigid;
public float Speed;
public float Power;
public GameObject Panel;
public Text ScorePoint;
private int Point = 0;
public Text HighScorePoint;

void Start()
{
    Rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    Panel.SetActive (false);
    HighScorePoint.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Scores");
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate (Vector2.right * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Rigid.AddForce (Vector2.up * Power * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }



// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! this is were it gives me an error !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!



    **if (int.Parse(ScorePoint.text) > int.Parse(HighScorePoint.text))**
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("Scores", ScorePoint.text);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Col)
{
    if (Col.gameObject.tag == "Pipe")
    {
        Panel.SetActive (true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Col)
{
    if (Col.gameObject.tag == "ScoreCollider")
    {
        Point++;
        ScorePoint.text = Point.ToString ();
    }
}
```

I have this code in my other game and it works correctly :

```
public float Speed;
private Rigidbody2D Rigid;
public float JumpPower;
public Text ScorePoint;
private int Point = 0;
public Text HighScorePoint;
public AudioSource CoinCollect;
public AudioSource Jump;
public AudioSource Laugh;
public AudioSource Scream;
private AudioSource[] Audios;

void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad (Scream);
    Audios = GetComponents<AudioSource> ();
    CoinCollect = Audios [0];
    Jump = Audios [1];
    Laugh = Audios [2];
    Scream = Audios [3];
    Rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    ScorePoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ScorePoint").GetComponent<Text> ();
    HighScorePoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("HighScorePoint").GetComponent<Text> ();
    HighScorePoint.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Scores");
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate (Vector2.right * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (transform.position.y < -2.1)
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Rigid.AddForce (Vector2.up * JumpPower * Time.deltaTime);
            Jump.Play ();
        }
    }

    if (int.Parse(ScorePoint.text) > int.Parse(HighScorePoint.text))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("Scores", ScorePoint.text);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Col)
{
    if (Col.gameObject.tag == "Enemies")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("CharacterSelection");
        Scream.Play ();
    }

    if (Col.gameObject.tag == "Coins")
    {
        Point++;
        ScorePoint.text = Point.ToString ();
        Destroy (Col.gameObject);
        CoinCollect.Play ();
    }

    if (Col.gameObject.tag == "Girls")
    {
        Point += 10;
        ScorePoint.text = Point.ToString ();
        Destroy (Col.gameObject);
        Laugh.Play ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well presumably either `ScorePoint.text` or `HighScorePoint.text` isn't a string representation of an integer. Without knowing what the values are, it's very hard to help any further...

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `HighScorePoint.text` is not null or empty before calling `int.Parse`.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ScorePoint.text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HighScorePoint.text))
{
    if (int.Parse(ScorePoint.text) > int.Parse(HighScorePoint.text))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Scores", ScorePoint.text);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

You can also use `TryParse` and avoid such error.

```
int tempScorePoint = 0;
int tempHighScorePoint = 0;

int.TryParse(ScorePoint.text, out tempScorePoint);
int.TryParse(HighScorePoint.text, out tempHighScorePoint);

if (int.TryParse(ScorePoint.text, out tempScorePoint) &&
    int.TryParse(HighScorePoint.text, out tempHighScorePoint))
{

    if (tempScorePoint > tempHighScorePoint)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Scores", ScorePoint.text);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

You can easily find out which `Text` component is `null` by inserting `Debug.Log` before that code that is causing the error.

```
Debug.Log(ScorePoint.text);
Debug.Log(HighScorePoint.text);
```

Comment: thanks..... i found the solution

it's the third time your answers helped me dear programmer

i wish you the best

Comment: Glad I was able to help